# jQuery returns false when input empty and press save but when type and click save still returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on my hyper link button and modal popup and then press save if input title empty it returns false which is correct, **but when I type in the input again and press save it still returns false.**

> Question If I click on my save button and input#title is empty how to make it return false when is empty but lets me save it when text in input?

**[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/PbMzvo)** // Updated with working code

It's some thing to do with this

```
if ($.trim(sel) == '') {
    return false;
} else {
    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,start) + replace +
    textarea.value.substring(end,len) + '\n' + id;
    $('#myLink').modal('hide');
}
```

Full Script

```
$('#myLink').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var text = getSelectedText();
    $('#title').val(text);
    $('#url').val('http://');
});    

function getSelectedText() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
    return sel;
}

var counter = 0;

$('#save-link').on('click', function(e) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);

    var replace = '[' + $('input#title').val() + ']' + '[' + counter + ']';

    var id = '\n\n   [' + counter + ']: ' + $('input#url').val();

    counter++;

    if ($.trim(sel) == '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,start) + replace +
        textarea.value.substring(end,len) + id;
        $('#myLink').modal('hide');
        $('.alert').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: variable "sel" refer to textarea not input#title

Comment: `var textarea = document.getElementById("message");` is looking for textarea on the title so it depends on whether `message` is emplty or not.

Comment: You can set the value of the "start" variable to 0.

Comment: try inputting some text in textarea then select all the text and click on the `Click here to add link` button it will work.

Comment: it helps if you put the html you're using

Comment: @ElmerDantas It's in my codepen example below the question

Comment: oh...sorry. I'll take a look

Comment: as mention it before...you're checking the value in the textarea not in the input inside the modal.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Need to check value in textarea as well as modal

Comment: I've tested your code and, I understand that you want the selected value on the textarea in the modal input...this is working and is not returning false when has value in the input. What do you want to achieve after clicking save?

Comment: @ElmerDantas I select text in textarea and has no text and click save then should return false. How ever if I retype in the input#title after it has return false then click on save it should continue with add / replacing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131774/discussion-between-elmer-dantas-and-wolfgang1983).

Comment: @ElmerDantas have it working now posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution now. I had to change couple things working [code](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/PbMzvo)

On this part I add trim()

```
$('#myLink').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var text = getSelectedText();
    $('#title').val(text.trim());
    $('#url').val('http://');
});
```

And this I added changed to this way

```
if ($('#title').val().length > 0) {
    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,start) + replace +
    textarea.value.substring(end,len) + '\n' + id;
    $('#myLink').modal('hide');
    $('#myLink form')[0].reset();
} else {

    return false;
}
```

From

```
if ($.trim(sel) == '') {
    return false;
} else {
    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,start) + replace +
    textarea.value.substring(end,len) + '\n' + id;
    $('#myLink').modal('hide');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Under "save" button's 'click' functionality, check the line

```
var len = textarea.value.length;
```

Validate based on the value of the variable `len` before proceeding further.